# Text indicator in PagerSlidingTabStrip in a fragment not sliding when pressing back

Tags: android

I have a fragment with viewPager inside it, I'm using PagerSlidingTabStrip library, I have three tabs, one of this tabs have a button that starts a new fragment, when pressing back and returning to the viewPager the text indicator is not switching any more, I have extended the adapter of the viewPager to be  FragmentStatePagerAdapter but it still not working.

Any ideas how to make the text indicator work after pressing back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you launched the new fragment with FramgnentManager instead of a ChildFragmentManager. I have been in to a solution like this and this is because the FrmagmentManager can not maintain the nesting fragment and that is why we have ChildFragmentManager.

If this doesn't solve your problem please let me know we can discuss.

Comment: I have already set the fragment manager of the adapter to be childFragmentManager but i'm having this problem.

Comment: The fragment manager for the adapter is childFragmentManager But, i didn't launch the fragment that starts from the button inside the viewPager with childFragmentManager, i changed it and added a container to the fragment and replaced the fragment. Now the viewPager is working fine.
Thank you for your answer :))

Comment: Perfect!!! This is the pure use of ChildFragmentManager and I was actually talking about new fragment's manager. Anyways am glad that it helped.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after reading your comment again :) Thanks again :)